# Java: reading raw JSON object string from a JSON file

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to read a JSON object from a JSON file in Java, as a string without any processing. The problem is that in the JSON file, the objects are not on a single line. (else it would have been easy to read them with scanner.nextLine() ) Also, in the program I will need to read the objects based on their ID, which is one of the object key.

If I map them to the corresponding POJO, later to convert it into a JSON string, I'll end up with a default value for attributes not present in a particular object and the key-value pair will show up in the string, which I don't want. I just need the original string as it as.

Any suggestion on the approach I can go with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: You will either need to give meaningful values for "not present" in your POJO, make a different POJO for each object, or use a parser that allows arbitrary JSON. (Unless you want to write code that looks at tokens from `JsonParser`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your problem is as stated in your sentence:

> *The problem is that in the JSON file, the objects are not on a single line*

There is a way to read the whole file as a single String using a `Scanner`:

```
String contents = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

The pattern `\Z` means "end of input", so the entire `InputStream` is read to the end.

To remove linefeed chars, replacing them with a space, so you get a single line to parse:

```
String contents = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next().replaceAll("\\R+", " ");
```

Comment: @4castle right. `\Z` is probably less obtuse. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Agreed I'll get the whole file contents in the string. But I want to retrieve any particular object from that string based on the ID. How can I do that?